# Findall data between tags

Tags: python, regex, parsing, rss, findall

I'm trying to essentially build a Python script that opens RSS news feeds and then compiles the news data it downloads into a HTML file which is then read as a 'newspaper' for a school assignment, therefore I cannot import things like Beautiful Soup and what not.

With this code I can extract data on one line however it doesn't work across multiple, after a fair bit of Googling I can't sus it out.

```
from urllib import urlopen

from re import findall

from webbrowser import open as webopen


url = 'http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topsongs/limit=10/xml' 


web_page_contents = urlopen(url).read()

print(re.findall(r'<item>(.*?)</item>', web_page_contents))
```

Comment: based off the Python docs for urlopen, you can use a lot of the same functions as a file object, including readlines. which should give you the functionality you're looking for

Comment: Briefly: `.` doesn't capture linefeeds.

Comment: Please show your web_page_contents.